# Bound on the difference-of-squares representation of a natural number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

1. Let $$m^2-n^2=r,$$ where $\gcd (m,n) =1,\;m>n>0,\;$ $m$ and $n$ are
   of opposite parity, and $r$ is an odd positive integer.

   Then, according to my study materials, determining all the $(m,n)$
   solutions involves systematically trying every $n$ such that  $1\leq
   n<\frac r2.$

   (For example: given $m^2-n^2=21,$ the only solutions $(5,2)$ and
   $(11,10)$ are determined by trying $n=1,2,3,...,10.)$

   **But why the upper bound $\frac r2$ for $n\,?$**
2. On a related note, for $m^2+n^2=r$ instead, I *am* able to see that
   $1\leq n<\sqrt \frac r2.$

   (Please correct me, though, if I'm wrong.)

P.S. [This Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223521/a2-b2-x-where-a-b-x-are-natural-numbers) is related (though [not](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34971/21813) a duplicate).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$r=m^2-n^2\ge(n+1)^2-n^2=2n+1$, so $n\le(r-1)/2$.

Answer (score 3):

If $(m+n)(m-n)=d$ and we take $m>n>0$, we can see that the largest difference between the two factors occurs when $m+n=d$, and $m-n=1$.

Taking the difference we get $2n=d-1$ so that the greatest possible value of $n$ is $\frac {d-1}2$.

Answer (score 2):

The differences between squares increase as the squares themselves increase. If $n,\ m > 10$ then the smallest difference possible is 
$$12^2 - 11^2 = (12 - 11)(12 + 11) = 23$$
which is already larger than your answer.

By the way, these are not Pythagorean triples.