# If $n$ is an odd integer, then there exist integers $a$ and $b$ such that $n=a^2-b^2$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

If $n$ is an odd integer, then there exist integers $a$ and $b$ such that $n=a^2-b^2$.

Am I supposed to use induction or a direct proof?

Comment: If $n$ is odd, then $n = 2m+1 = (m+1)^2-m^2$.

Comment: Why not try both? Different proofs offer different insights.

Comment: Induction proofs offer zero insight.

Comment: If $n=k^2-(k-1)^2$ then $n+2=k^2-(k^2-2k+1)+2=k^2-k^2+2k-1+2=k^2+2k+1-k^2=(k+1)^2-k^2$.  That is insightful, @vadim123, I got the insight that the direct proof proves the induction.

Comment: Also [Prove every odd integer is the difference of two squares](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263101/prove-every-odd-integer-is-the-difference-of-two-squares)

Answer (score 5):

Trying to express $n=a^2-b^2$, we note that $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$ and so we try the simplest solution $a+b=n$ and $a-b=1$. This leads to $a=(n+1)/2$ and $b=(n-1)/2$, which are indeed integers because $n$ is odd.

This approach also works for $n$ even, but we have to try the next simplest solution: $a+b=n/2$ and $a-b=2$. This leads to $n$ having to be a multiple of $4$ and $a=n/4+1$ and $b=n/4-1$.

This completely characterizes the numbers $n$ that can be expressed as the difference of two squares: $n$ is odd or $n$ is a multiple of $4$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* $2k+1 = 1\cdot \left((k+1)+k\right)$.

Comment: This would be better off as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

$n=2k+1$; If $b=k$ then, $k^2+2k+1=(k+1)^2=a^2$,  so $b=k$ and $a=k+1$