# When is $n^2 - 8056$ a perfect square?

Tags: number-theory

When is $n^2 - 8056$ a perfect square ? What is a generalized solution for $n^2 - c$ ?

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Hint:* $n^2 - 8056 = m^2$ iff $(n-m)(n+m)= 8056$. This equation has integer solutions iff $8056$ can be decomposed into two factors of the same parity.

This argument holds in general: an integer is a difference of two squares iff it is odd or a multiple of $4$.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/547420/589

Comment: Nice. And this gives explicit solutions for $n$ too (after factoring of course). Write $m$ here $m=8056 = xy$; $x$ and $y$ positive integers both $x$ and $y$ even ($m$ a multiple of 4)  or both $x$ and $y$ odd $(m$ odd). Then $n=\frac{x+y}{2}$.