# Difference between the squares of consecutive integers

Tags: number-theory

I just realized that the difference between $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$ is exactly the $n$th odd number. For example: $5^2 - 4^2 = 9$, the 5th odd number. Is there a proof of this that I can study? This is just my nephew and I playing with series and simple programming problems.

Comment: $$(n+1)^2=n^2+2n+1$$ subtract $n^2$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  [Every odd number is the difference of two squares](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263101/prove-every-odd-integer-is-the-difference-of-two-squares)

Comment: Mind-blowing, @J.W.Tanner! Thank you both!