# I have the following Diophantine equation $x=y^2-z^2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [$a^2-b^2 = x$ where $a,b,x$ are natural numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223521/a2-b2-x-where-a-b-x-are-natural-numbers)

> 1. Show that for every positive odd integer $x$ there exist integers $y$ and $z$ such
>      that $(x, y, z)$ is a solution
> 2. For which positive even integers $x$ do there exist integers $y$ and $z$ such that
>      $(x, y, z)$ is a solution

I have thought about trying a solution through congruence modulo but I head nowhere.

Here is my work so far:

[image]

But I think maybe infinite descents would be more appropriate but just don't know how to do it.