# Number of integer solutions $(x, y)$ of $x(x+6) = y^2 + k$ for different integer values of $k$

Tags: diophantine-equations, integers

Let $n$ be the number of pairs  $(x, y)$  of integer solutions to the following equation:$$x(x+6) = y^2 + k$$

Can there be an integer $m$, $k$ can be given an integer value so that $n=m$ ?

Comment: Shouldn't $n$ depend on $k$ in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

A hint: Put $z=x+3$ and simplify to an equation containing $z^2-y^2$. You can then apply a well-known analysis of differences between squares equal to a given integer, as in answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223521/a2-b2-x-where-a-b-x-are-natural-numbers).