# Can $n$ be expressed as $a^b-c^d$, where $a,b,c,d,$ and $n$ are natural numbers, not necessary distinct?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, factorial, perfect-powers

Can $n$ be expressed as $a^b-c^d$, where $a,b,c,d,$ and $n$ are natural numbers, not necessary distinct, and $b$ and $d$ can not be both equal to $1$?

For example, when $n=1319$, then $2^{11}-3^6=1319$.

What if $n=2019$?

What if $n=100!$? (! represents the factorial)

For $n=100!$, I do not need to find $a,b,c,$ and $d$. I just want to know if it is possible to be of the given form or no.

Comment: @projectilemotion That is trivial. Trivial solutions are not to be considered here. Thanks for that, I will edit my post.

Comment: My earlier (deleted) comment: What about the trivial case $b=d=1$?

Comment: $2019 = 1010^2 - 1009^2$ (you can adapt this for any odd $n$).

Comment: Related to Pillai's conjecture that for every fixed $n$ only finite many solutions exist. But only the case $n=1$ is completely solved.

Comment: According to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/223530/323432), it is *always* possible in the case $b=d=2$ for $n$ odd and $n$ divisible by $4$.

Comment: In fact : $(k+1)^2-(k-1)^2=4k$

Comment: @projectilemotion, so useful ,,, thanks. So for $100!$ it is possible too since it is divisible by $4$.

Comment: Yes, indeed, we have that:
$$a=\frac{100!}{4}+1,\quad c=\frac{100!}{4}-1$$

Comment: If we exclude trivial case ($b,d>1$) it seems quite challenging to find $n=6$ already...

Comment: $3^3-5^2$ works for n=2. $13^3-3^7$ works for $n=10$. Haven't figured out 6 yet.

Comment: $18=3^3-3^2$, $22=7^2-3^3$. $26=3^3-1^d$ for any $d$. $n=30$ is fun, $83^2-19^3=30$. $n=14$ seems like another tricky one, along with 6.

Comment: for a difference of numbers to give a third number, the numbers must be same remainder mod all of it's factors.

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari Based on what you've stated, if I understand correctly, you can have $a = n + 1$, $b = 1$, $c = 1$ and $d = 2$. I think you may to add that $c \neq 1$ to avoid this degenerate solution. Also, as stated in Oscar Lanzi's answer, you probably would want to have neither $b$ or $d$ be $1$.

Answer (score 2):

You can write any multiple of $4$ by using the identity $$(x+1)^2-(x-1)^2=4x$$Since, $100!$ is a multiple of $4$, you can write $$100!=\left(\frac{100!}{4}+1\right)^2-\left(\frac{100!}{4}-1\right)^2$$

Answer (score 1):

Well, if $b$ and $d$ cannot *both* be equal to $1$ them $2019$ may be rendered as $2025-6=45^2-6^1$.  If it is meant that *neither* $b$ nor $d$ can equal $1$ then you can use a difference of squares, the choice with the smallest numbers for $2019$ being $338^2-335^2$.

All odd numbers and all multiples of $4$ may be rendered as differences of squares.